# How to make certain things on a site editable from the django admin?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, edit

How to make certain things, like an about section, or social links, on a site editable from the django admin?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. It sounds like you either want a CMS, or something lightweight like Django chunks, or you could build something like that yourself.

Comment: @Alasdair thank you. I think Django chunks is what I am looking for.

Comment: If it's what you're looking for, accept @j.doe answer so anyone else who has the same issue will be pointed in the right direction :)

Comment: @Riyaaz-0 Okay, but I have to wait 2 days before I accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Django chunks to accomplish the editing of certain content from the admin.